# += appends to stack in Scala 2.7.7; :+ does not seem to work in Scala 2.8.0

Tags: collections, stack, scala-2.8, mutable

Using Scala 2.7.7, this works as expected:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
...
var x = new Stack[String]
x += "Hello"
println(x.top)
```

After changing to Scala 2.8.0, the += should be replaced by :+. However, this does not append to the stack: java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list.

Am I overlooking something basic?

Answer (score 1):

`:+`, defined in SeqLike, copies the stack and append the element into the new stack, and return that. So `x` is not modified.

Probably you want `.push()` instead ([example](http://www.ideone.com/VDofi)).

```
var x = new Stack[String]
x.push("Hello")
println(x.top)
```